# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is not valid before

Tags: jwt

My scenario is when we are testing with user logging-in and logging-out multiple times, we are getting error randomly -

Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 **[13:58:41](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPTeG.png)** GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token is not valid before '06/22/2021 **13:58:42**'"

Backend API in dot net core, where we are generating and validating JWT tokens,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tokens have the [`nbf` (JWT Not Before) Claim](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.5), when verifying a token with `nbf` the current time must be at or after that timestamp. These timestamps are UNIX timestamps in seconds.

What may be happening is

- when you produce these tokens with `nbf` the claim value is ceiled to the nearest second, instead of being floored.
- your clock may be skewed between the producer and consumer

In both cases the recommended way is described in the RFC

> Implementers MAY
> provide for some small leeway, usually no more than a few minutes, to
> account for clock skew.

Some verification option like clock skew or clock tolerance may be present which you need to set to some acceptable value, e.g. 5 seconds to accommodate for tiny clock skew or floor/ceil discrepancies.